# Firefly mating displays

Tags: entomology, environment

I live in the northeast US, and really enjoy firefly displays at dusk in the summer. However, when paying attention this summer, I noticed that the fireflies were not displaying every night, but somewhat irregularly, and only over a short period (both within an evening and across the season). I could not figure out what combination of environmental conditions were associated with their display behavior. What are the environmental conditions in which fireflies are most likely to engage in light displays in the temperate eastern US?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE, thank you for asking a specific question and for taking the tour :)